# transpose pandas df based on multiple header rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following df from a vendor:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  agg metrics 10/20/22    10/20/22    10/21/22    10/21/22
title     content title season      episode     start       hours       start       hours
book      blue          1           3           2           2           5           2
movie     orange        2           4           11          4           7           4
```

I need the output like this:

```
title   content title   season  episode date    start   hours
book    blue            1       3       10/20/22    2   2
book    blue            1       3       10/21/22    5   2
movie   orange          2       4       10/20/22    11  4
movie   orange          2       4       10/21/22    7   4
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('file')
df = df.drop(labels=0, axis=0)
df1 = df.melt(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'agg metrics'],var_name='Date', value_name='Value')
```

but this doesn't return the proper output.  apologies for not knowing how to represent this properly.  hopefully my IP/OP helps.

Essentially, i'm having trouble transposing **multiple headers**.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide the original CSV in a text format.

Comment: Where are you getting dates from? Is there another dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston you're too fast!  i was editing it when you commented.

Comment: @SomeDude you're too fast!  i was editing it when you commented.

Comment: I m 2 secs earlier :) JK. The columns you have are multiindex? or the first row is only the column header?

Comment: all i care about from the first header is the dates, then i need to just transpose, but i can't seem to maintain the dfs integrity across the transposes to get the desired output.  sadly, i cannot change how they give us these tables.  @SomeDude

Comment: @SomeDude based on context i'll assume that yes, they're multi index, though i've never worked with multi index tables.

Comment: read the csv with two row headers and for col index. Then stack level 0.

Comment: @QuangHoang can you please expand on the stack level?  i'm getting an error when attempting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this and this is what QuangHoang's thought too I believe:

```
# Read csv with top two rows as headers resulting in multiindex, from your code I figure 
# you are not doing that.
df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(
        """
Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 1,Unnamed: 2,agg metrics,10/20/22,10/20/22,10/21/22,10/21/22
title,content title,season,episode,start,hours,start,hours
book,blue,1,3,2,2,5,2
movie,orange,2,4,11,4,7,4
        """
    ),
    header=[0, 1],
)

# Then filter columns that are date like and stack at level 0 and reset_index
t = df.filter(regex="\d+/\d+/\d+")
t1 = t.stack(0).rename_axis(["", "date"]).reset_index(1)

# Then get other columns and reindex to the index of the intermediate output you got above.
t2 = df[df.columns.difference(t.columns)].droplevel(0, axis=1).reindex(t1.index)

# Then concat both along axis 1
out = pd.concat([t2, t1], axis=1)

print(out)

   title content title  season  episode      date  hours  start
                                                               
0   book          blue       1        3  10/20/22      2      2
0   book          blue       1        3  10/21/22      2      5
1  movie        orange       2        4  10/20/22      4     11
1  movie        orange       2        4  10/21/22      4      7
```

Comment: I am getting this error when running t2:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

Comment: What version of pandas is yours? `pd.__version__`

Comment: '0.23.0'.  it did appear to work without droplevel.

t2 = df[df.columns.difference(t.columns)].reindex(t1.index)

Comment: Not sure why it worked and how. But I highly recommend upgrading your pandas, that's a very old version and not just for this activity but I m sure there are several performance enhancements done after that version.

Comment: i think it may be implemented in pandas 0.24.0 based on errors i found.

this seems to have done the right thing and explain "why" and "how":

t2 = df[df.columns.difference(t.columns)].reindex(t1.index)
t2.columns = t2.columns.get_level_values(1)

Comment: Ok so you could get what you wanted then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
# mock csv file with StringIO
s = StringIO('''
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  agg metrics  10/20/22    10/20/22    10/21/22    10/21/22
title     content title  season      episode     start       hours       start       hours
book      blue          1           3           2           2           5           2
movie     orange        2           4           11          4           7           4
''')

# forget `sep` argument if your file is Comma Separated Value
df = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\s\s+', header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1,2,3])
df.stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

Output (rename your columns accordingly):

```
title level_0 level_1  level_2  level_3 Unnamed: 0  hours  start
0        book    blue        1        3   10/20/22      2      2
1        book    blue        1        3   10/21/22      2      5
2       movie  orange        2        4   10/20/22      4     11
3       movie  orange        2        4   10/21/22      4      7
```